# Laravel migration without losing the real data

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, migrate

Is there a possible way to run artisan command to refresh a database without any lost any data?

In my past working, laravel with propel can make the database but doesn't lose any real data with `propel:migration:diff`.

Anyway with laravel default artisan migrate can it do it the same way?

Comment: What are you changing in your new migration?

Comment: This might be helpful `https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands`

Comment: I am just want to add few column in userTable, however, it require to open a new datatable.php to insert to keep the database record. But I like the propel schema method to diff database and do migration without lost any data

Answer (score 4):

By definition, refreshing the database (`php artisan migrate:refresh`) means you are removing all of the data.

The idea is that you're rolling back and re-running all of your migrations which would likely mean that your schema has changed a bit if not significantly and therefore the current data in your database might not match the new schema (and if it did then why would you be refreshing).

A better approach is to add to your migrations to alter columns and tables as you move through your development. In fact, this is one of the main advantages of having this type of "version control" for your DB.